# Do I have to include the auto_increment in my indexes?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple mysql table with five columns:

```
id: auto_increment (primary)
id_symbol: INT(4)
id_category: INT(4)
id_sector: INT(4)
name: VARCHAR(100)
```

I would like to create an index for `id_simbol, id_category, id_sector` so ONE index for those columns. My question is:

DO i also have to add the id (auto_increment) do this index so four columns in total?

Thank you!

Comment: If your storage engine is InnoDB, the PK gets included as first column in each index automatically anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to add `id` column to that index.